# How can I color a pattern?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, cgcontext

Im using the following code to draw a pattern to make the stroke look like chalk-dust. However I can't find any way to change the color of the stroke if I'm using patterns. Is there any way to do this?

```
    CGAffineTransform patternTransform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    const CGPatternCallbacks kPatternCallbacks = {0, DrawPatternCellCallback, NULL};
    const CGRect patternBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 8);
    CGPatternRef strokePattern = CGPatternCreate(
                                                 NULL,
                                                 patternBounds,
                                                 patternTransform,
                                                 8, // horizontal spacing
                                                 8,// vertical spacing
                                                 kCGPatternTilingNoDistortion,
                                                 true,
                                                 &kPatternCallbacks);
    CGFloat color1[] = {1.0, 0, 1.0, 1};
    CGColorSpaceRef patternSpace = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(cacheContext, patternSpace);
    CGContextSetStrokePattern(cacheContext, strokePattern, color1);

   // CGColorSpaceRef patternSpace = CGColorSpaceCreatePattern(NULL);
   // CGContextSetStrokeColorSpace(cacheContext, patternSpace);
    CGContextSetLineCap(cacheContext, kCGLineCapRound);
       CGContextSetLineWidth(cacheContext, 4);


  //Callback


void DrawPatternCellCallback(void *info, CGContextRef cgContext)
{
    UIImage *patternImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"chalk_brush.png"];
    CGContextDrawImage(cgContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, 8, 8), patternImage.CGImage);
}
```

Comment: The color is in the callback. Show the callback. Do you understand about "masking" patterns?

Answer (score 0):

The color is all in the callback (which you have not shown in your question). Here's the pattern-drawing documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_patterns/dq_patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH206-BBCJAJEC

So, as you can see, you either use a colored pattern with different callbacks for different colors, or you use a stencil ("masking") pattern. For the latter, in your `CGPatternCreate` call, you would say `false` where you are now saying `true`. You can then set the stroke pattern or fill pattern, passing a color array.

Comment: changed to false but still got the same problem. Do i need to change something else?

Comment: How do I know? I don't know what you're doing, do I? You haven't shown the callbacks as I asked, have you? Look - the sample code is right there in the docs. It works. Start by copying it.

Comment: Updated with callback.

Comment: So what's actually happening? I don't see any drawing taking place. What is your drawing code and what do you actually get? In any case, I repeat: start by just copying and pasting Apple's code right into your app. It works. Now start changing it bit by bit. If it stops working, go backwards. :)